# Center of a quotient of a free group

Tags: group-theory, free-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I encountered the following statement while going through an old result by C.F.Miller (Ref. The Schur Multiplier, Gregory Karpilovsky, Theorem 2.6.6, Page 72):

Let $G=F/R$ be a presentation of an arbitrary group (i.e., $F$ is a free group and $R$ is a normal subgroup of $F$). Then $R/[F,R]$ is precisely equal to the center of $F/[F,R]$.

It is obvious that $R/[F,R]$ is a central subgroup of $F/[F,R]$. The converse doesn't seem so easy for me: for any $x \in F$ with $[F, x] \subseteq [F,R]$, then we should have $x \in R$. Taking $F = Z$ gives a counterexample for sure. However, I don't see any easy counterexample for any free group $F$ with rank at least two.

Comment: Could you describe your counterexample in more details, please?

Comment: If $F$ has rank $1$, i.e., $F \cong {\mathbb{Z}}$, then $[F, R] = 1$ and any proper subgroup $R$ of $F$ cannot be equal to $Z(F) = F$.

Comment: I have just checked that the proof of Miller's Theorem works from the fact $R/[F,R]$ is a central subgroup (no need of this to be the exact center). So, this should be a typo/oversight in the proof I mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

Any finite  presentation of a finite cyclic group, like $G = \langle a,b \mid a^2,b \rangle$ gives the same contradiction.

$G \cong  F/R \cong \frac{F/[F,R]}{R/[F,R]}$ is cyclic with $R/F,R] \le Z(F/[F,R])$, so $F/[F,R]$ is abelian.

But there are other finite groups, like $Q_8$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/403172)) that cannot occur as $G/Z(G)$, so they give rise to further counterexamples, such as $\langle a,b \mid a^2=b^2, a^{-1}ba=b^{3} \rangle$.

Comment: Thanks Derek. One can take a direct product of a finite cyclic group with any finite non-abelian group. Then even $F/[F,R]$ is non-abelian and give a counterexample.